# How do I delete part of the lines of a file with sed?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

So I need to format a file that has the sudo group on the line of a file with bash. It looks like this by default:

```
linenumber:sudo:x:user1,user2,etc...
```

So I want to use sed to make it look like this:

```
user1,
user2,
etc...
```

(I don't need the extra space in between, the formatting just made it so if there wasn't an extra space it would look like this: user1,user2,etc...)

So to do this I need to find the last : in the file and then format it the correct way. I don't need to use sed, but I assume it is the answer. Thanks in advance for answers!

Comment: Does this file have multiple lines? A better (And properly formatted for legibility) example would be useful.

Comment: `"...I need to find the last : in the file..."`?? Do you mean in the line with `sudo` or do you really mean last `':'` in the **file**? If simply in the line with `sudo` then `sed 's/^.*:sudo:x://;s/,/,\n/g' file`, or it last `':'` in-file `tac file | sed '0,/:/s/^.*://;s/,/,\n/g'`

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/sudo/{s/.*://;s/,/&\n/g}' file
```

For any line that contains `sudo`, remove up to and including the last `:` in the line and then replace each `,` by a `,` followed by a newline.

Answer (score 1):

With Bash builtins, getting everything after the last colon from a string you already have in a variable,

```sh
string=${string##*:}
echo "${string//,/$'\n'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use cut, with **:** as the deliminator. Searching for position 4, like this: **1:2:3:4**

```
cut -d ':' -f 4
```

To format it to the example you wanted, combine cut with tr to replace comma with a new line.

```
cut -d ':' -f 4 | tr ',' '\n'
```